# Upgraded to El Capitan and gulp no longer works

Tags: node.js, gulp, osx-elcapitan

So at work we use gulp and outside of generally being shown how to run it, I really don't understand how it works.  In terminal I'd cd into the project, sudo npm install, then run gulp and that was that.  I've since upgraded my OS to el Capitan and now I get this error:

```
Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/FTW/gulpfile.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129
    gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:19
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

I've tried looking this up, but as a complete novice to terminal, command line, etc., I'm completely lost as to what exactly is wrong and how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit: I have no idea what this did, but it's seemed to have worked?  At least for this one project; I have no idea if this is a per-project local fix or otherwise.

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either

```
sudo npm install -g gulp
```

or (some users reported that it is a rights problem) try

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin/node_modules
sudo npm install -g gulp
```

Comment: Thanks; I did install it globally.  I tried the chown but it says, "chown: /usr/local/bin/node_modules: No such file or directory."  I have no idea what this directory and permissions thing is. :/  I did seem to fix it another way (edited into my question) .. just no idea what it did.  Anyway, thanks again.